# I have a functionality where i can copy the tokens which has some errors

Tags: clarion

[image: error message]
[image]
[image]
Errorcode is 05 Access Denied/48 Unable to Log Transaction, this has come from RTL, not a custom function message, and only happens sometime when tokens are being fetched from database.

Everytime I trigger this function I use to get different error, what might be the reason, I have attached the screenshot but I wanted to know the root cause, why these errors are different everytime, would these be a TPS database related error.

Application is developed in Clarion 6.0 and compiled i n 8.0 and these issues don’t come up regulary, this errors are intermittent and occur at any stage, if it works smooth it doesn’t cause any issues but once issue pops up it will keep coming, any idea on these, do you think these is the code issue or can be a clarion custom error?

Files are on network drive and db is topspeed.PFA